# Will an iOS app that only opens a UIWebView and uses push notification get rejected from apple?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an application that does exactly 2 things.

1) Opens a UIWebView

2) Uses push notification

I am opening a UIWebView where i load an external URL , and there the user can subscribe to various kinds of events. After he subscribes he can get push notifications about them.

I am asking because some people told me that their apps got rejected when they were just loading an external URL , because apple said it could better be a web page and not an iOS app.

But in my case where i use push notifications? Does it count differently?

Comment: How did it go? I need to do the same thing

Comment: also want to know how it went!!!

Comment: for anyone wondering, you can use something like GoNative.io which basically does the same thing with a few extra bells and whistles (native nav etc). We're wondering if we even need that though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `WebView` only apps are beeng rejected is because they dont use any of the features that the framework is offering. I got in an application that had only one view for log in, and after log in, the response was URL from server that I was showing in `WebView`.
You will never know unless you try, but I think it will get in.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully submitted 3 apps which are all WebViews but with Push Notification functionality. As long as you have Push Notifications in your app you will meet the guidelines of having framework dependant features in your app rather than just being a simple WebView in a mobile app.

Comment: YMMV: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69334047/380607

Answer (score 0):

> "Your app did not include iOS features. App Store apps should use native iOS buttons and include iOS features other than just web views, push notifications, or sharing."

source: [Apple rejecting Ionic apps](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/apple-rejecting-ionic-apps/153980), date: Jan, 2019

> “Your app provides a limited user experience as it is not sufficiently different from a mobile browsing experience. Specifically, we notice that most of the app content links out to Safari. As such, the experience it provides is similar to the general experience of using Safari. Including iOS features such as push notifications, Core Location, and sharing do not provide a robust enough experience to be appropriate for the App Store. … the App Store does not accept or distribute web apps.”

source: [App Store Rejection 4.2 - Design: Minimum Functionality](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/app-store-rejection-4-2-design-minimum-functionality-my-first-after-2-years-of-ionic/200908), date: Dec 2020, But seems [it was resolved](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/app-store-rejection-4-2-design-minimum-functionality-my-first-after-2-years-of-ionic/200908/9).

Conclusion: YMMV = Your Mileage May Vary.